# Iterate through sub-directories in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, r-raster

I have a large directory with 365 sub-directories that contain images for each day of the year. I created a function that I want to apply to each of the images within these sub directories. At the moment, this is what I have:

```
library(raster)
library(zebu)

#List all of the 365 sub-directories within my main directory
days <- list.files(full.names = F , recursive =F, pattern='*X2000*')

#Apply my function to each directory within "days"
for(j in 1:length(days)){

    named <- paste0("full_",j)

    in.list <- list.files(recursive = T, full.names = F)

    stitched <- mosaicList(in.list)

    writeRaster(stitched, path='D:/Scratch/DataConvert/Daymet_Data/Full/' , 
    filename=named, overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

The goal of this loop is to apply the function "mosaicList" to the images within each sub-directory. The problem is, when the for loop runs, the object "in.list" contains the same sub-directories as "days" instead of listing the images within the sub-directories. As a result it tries to run my function for every sub-directory at the same time and I get the error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 14.2 Gb
```

I am new to R so I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong. Does anyone have any insight into fixing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue with the `list.files` in your loop:

```
in.list <- list.files(recursive = T, full.names = F)
```

The default path parameter for list.files is ".", which is the current directory. Perhaps changing to:

```
in.list <- list.files(path=days[j], recursive = T, full.names = T)
```

Will fix.

Comment: When I tried your suggestion, my object `in.list` ended up being empty. If I change my first line to `for ((j in 1:length(days)){` and follow your suggestion, my `in.list` is created and lists the images in the directory properly but j becomes `1L` instead of the image it is supposed to be.

Comment: Oops, I didn't change `full.names = T`. I made the change and it is working now. Thanks for the help!