# Iterate over multiple subdirectories in r

Tags: r

I am trying to iterate over a directory with two levels of folders, the last of which contains a variable number of files. I have used three nested for loops which runs without error, however listA and list_num are both empty so there is no result i.e. print(l), similar to issues noted in [Iterate through sub-directories in for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892902/iterate-through-sub-directories-in-for-loop-in-r). I have tried multiple versions without change in result. Any advice would be welcomed.

```
dir <- "C:/Users/j/xyzDropbox/project1/HRData/Day1_20220905"  
files <- list.files(path=dir, full.names=FALSE)
for (f in 1:length(files)) { # level 1 folders
listA <- basename(list.files(path=files[f], recursive = T, full.names = FALSE))
  for (a in 1:length(listA)) { # level 2 folders
    list_num <- basename(list.files(path=listA[a], recursive = T, full.names = FALSE))
    for (l in 1:length(list_num)) { # files
       print(l) # in full code specific tasks executed here
    }}}
```

Comment: as you already seem to know about the recursive option, why not simply open all folders from the get go?

Comment: Maybe change to `files <- list.dirs(path=dir, full.names=TRUE)` ,  `listA <- list.dirs(path=files[f], full.names=TRUE)` and `list_num <- list.files(path=listA[a], full.names=TRUE)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have arrived at. Thanks for input.

```
for (f in 1:length(files)) { 
  
  listA <- list.files(path=paste0(dir,"/",files[f]), recursive = F, full.names = FALSE)
 
  for (a in 1:length(listA)) { print(a) #complete specific calls
  }}
```